# How to minimize this set function?

Tags: discrete-optimization, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I'm considering a very interesting problem. For a graph $G=(V,E)$, either directed or undirected, if we define
\begin{equation}
\rho(G)=\max\{|\lambda|\;|\;\lambda\text{ eigenvalue of $G$'s adjacency matrix} \}
\end{equation}
then we could define a set function $F$, which maps every subgraph $\tilde{G}$ of $G$ to $\rho(\tilde{G})$.

Given a $k$ ($0<k<|V|$), what I am primarily considering is the following: can we find a the subgraph of $G$ with smallest $F$ value in the set of all subgraphs in $G$ with $|V|-k$ nodes? If not, can we find one with certain approximation factor?

### My Thinking

A very natural way is a greedy method, i.e., iteratively delete one node that decreases the set function value the most, remove the node and renew the graph, stop when I have deleted $k$ nodes. However, this set function seems not neither be submodular nor supermodular. **So my question is, could this greedy method have some approximation rate close to optimal?**

I will appreciate it so much if someone can give me some enlightenment!

Comment: What is meant by "[...] which function every subgraph $\tilde G$ of $G$ to $ρ(\tilde G)$"? Is a verb missing?

Comment: Thank you @pluton, this "function" is a verb, means "maps", i.e., $F:\tilde{G}\rightarrow \rho(\tilde{G})$, sorry for not clearly writen

Comment: Still welcome some valuable comments!